# How to correctly pass a formatted datetime into a HTTP request?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, datetime

I was tasked with writing a test for a REST service by calling its endpoint with an HTTP request. One part of the HTTP request should be a date (to filter only items modified after that date). The problem is, that I cannot seem to properly pass the date into the HTTP request.

This is how the endpoint is defined in the Rest Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{resourceType}/{application}")
public Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> findByTypeAndApplication(@PathVariable("resourceType") ResourceType type,
        @PathVariable("application") String application,
        @RequestParam(name = "modifiedAfter", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") Date modifiedAfter)
```

It is the "modifiedAfter" parameter that is giving me trouble. Trying to pass a date formatted according to the "pattern" does not appear to work for me. After parsing into URL, the request would look like this:

```
http://.../LANGTEXT/INTEGRATION-EXCEL-TEST?modifiedAfter=2019-06-11%2021%3A28%3A44
```

I also tried restassured.given to build the requests. I tried to pass the parameter in the address itself, as a param(), as a queryParam(), and as a formParam(). I tried to pass it both as a formatted string (as per the pattern), and as a Date object. Nothing seems to work.

I cannot change the controller itself (including the date format), so I need to properly pass the date in the HTTP request.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Thanks, Petr

Comment: This is encoded automatically, and on server side would be decoded. I dont think anything is wrong here. is soemthing not working. Remember that space would be replaced with %20 when encoded.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The misbehavior was caused by something further down at the backend. The parameter itself was passed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

On server side, spring does this automatically. You don't need specify date pattern.